# Dynamic segments not getting passed to route params

Tags: ember.js

I'm using Ember 1.0 and Ember-Data 1.0Beta. I'm trying to pass a dynamic segment to a route like so:

```
@resource 'organization', path: 'organizations/:organization_id', ->
  @route 'edit'
```

Then in my edit route:

```
Whistlr.OrganizationEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->
    @store.find('organization', params.organization_id)
```

Unfortunately, the params hash turns up empty. When I inspect it in the console, it's just a simple `{}`. In turn, `params.organization_id` is null. This happens even when the URL looks correct: "/organizations/1/edit`

This closely resembles the setup in the [Ember guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/#toc_dynamic-models). What could I be getting wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is the dynamic segment (`:organization_id`) is part of the `organization` resource and not the `edit` resource. This means that only `OrganizationRoute` will have access to the `params.organization_id`.

However, if you need the model in your `OrganizationEditRoute` you can use `modelFor` to access it.

```
Whistlr.OrganizationEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->
    @modelFor('organization')
```

This lets the `OrganizationRoute` load the model from it's dynamic segment and then the `OrganizationEditRoute` can just simply access that model like so.

Comment: Thank you, Ryan. This explains a lot. I'd seen modelFor in a lot of examples but didn't really know how it was supposed to be used until now.